# Show/Hide Div - and make the "Read More" button hide on click

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on some Javascript to make "Read More" and "Read Less" buttons to expand and collapse text.  I have this almost perfectly working like I hoped for, but I can't figure out the final syntax.

I have my progress marked up here:

https://jsfiddle.net/bmorrical/j17zfy7e/

Can someone point me in the right direction on how to:

1. Remove "Read More" when it's clicked
2. Show "Read More" when "Read Less" is clicked

I'm just trying to toggle the "Read More" on click, thank you.

JS

```
function show() {
   document.getElementById('scritta').className='visiblediv'; 
}
function hide() {
   document.getElementById('scritta').className='hiddendiv'; 
}

var p1 = document.getElementById("p1");
p1.onclick = show;
var p2 = document.getElementById("p2");
p2.onclick = hide;
```

CSS

```
.visiblediv {
    display: block;
}

.hiddendiv {
    display: none;
}
```

HTML

```
<p>This is sample text to represent a paragraph.</p>
<button id="p1">Read More</button>
<div id="scritta" class="hiddendiv">This is more sample text to represent additional text after the button has expanded the text.<button id="p2">Read Less</button></div>
```

Comment: I'm not against it, I just haven't tried jQuery.  Javascript/jQuery isn't my strongest skill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply the same `hiddendiv` and `visiblediv` classes to the button ID:

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j17zfy7e/1/)

```
function show() {
    document.getElementById('scritta').className = 'visiblediv';
    document.getElementById('p1').className = 'hiddendiv';
}

function hide() {
    document.getElementById('scritta').className = 'hiddendiv';
    document.getElementById('p1').className = 'visiblediv';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using jquery you could do something with `toggle()` and `hide()`

```
$('#p2').hide();

$('#p1').click(function(){
    $('#p1').toggle();
    $('#p2').toggle();
});

$('#p2').click(function(){
    $('#p1').toggle();
    $('#p2').toggle();
});
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j17zfy7e/6/

Answer (score 0):

Something like that ?

```
$('#p1').on('click', function(){
    $(this).css('visibility', 'none');
    $('#p2').css('visibility', 'visible');
});

$('#p2').on('click', function(){
    $(this).css('visibility', 'none');
    $('#p1').css('visibility', 'visible');
});
```

Simply add visibility:hidden to #p2 in your css or work with classes

```
$('#p1').on('click', function(){
        $(this).addClass('hidden');
        $('#p2').addClass('visible');
    });
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the p1 your hidden/visible classes like this, when you call your show,hide functions.

```
function show() {
   document.getElementById('scritta').className='visiblediv'; 
   document.getElementById('p1').className='hiddendiv'; 
}

function hide() {
   document.getElementById('scritta').className='hiddendiv'; 
   document.getElementById('p1').className='visiblediv'; 
}

var p1 = document.getElementById("p1");
p1.onclick = show;
var p2 = document.getElementById("p2");
p2.onclick = hide;
```

[A working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lezk4jtf/)